# Jira integration with bitbucket

Tags: python, git, bitbucket, jira, webhooks

I have integrated Jira with bitbucket. I have also enabled smart commits. I want to force branch names to include valid jira tickets. I wrote a python script to do the same. I placed the python script as a snippet in my workspace in bitbucket with public visibility. The python script works fine when tested separately, hwoever, when, I placed the raw link of snippet in webhooks, it throwing 401 error. I am not able to understand the issue. Here is my python code.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import sys
import requests

def jira_api_validate_ticket(ticket):
    jira_base_url = "https://<comopany_name>.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/"
    username = "<username>"
    password = "<api token>"  # For API token authentication

    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    response = requests.get(f"{jira_base_url}{ticket}", headers=headers, auth=(username, password))
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return True  # Ticket is valid
    else:
        return False  # Ticket is not valid

def main():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        oldrev, newrev, refname = line.strip().split()
        branch_name = refname.split('/')[-1]

        # Extract Jira ticket from branch name (e.g., PROJ-1234)
        jira_ticket = re.search(r'[A-Z]+-[0-9]+', branch_name)
        

        if not jira_ticket:
            print(f"Error: Branch name '{branch_name}' does not contain a valid Jira ticket.")
            sys.exit(1)

        # Use Jira API to validate the Jira ticket (pseudo-code)
        if not jira_api_validate_ticket(jira_ticket.group()):
            print(f"Error: Jira ticket '{jira_ticket.group()}' is not valid.")
            sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org) or self-hosted?